# finding second position in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to pull the name of the students who stood second positions from grade 1 to grade 12. each grade has separate databases with similar table structure

I have the following data:

**Set 1**

```
uid marks
1    10
2    20
3    17
4    17 
5    20
6    20
```

**Set 2**

```
uid marks
1    10
2    20
3    17
4    17 
5    20
6    17
7    20
```

**I need a query which can say uid 3,4 are second in set 1 and 3,4,6 are second in set 2.** 
i need it in a single query because there are several set of databases

what could be the possible way?

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM  TBL WHERE marks ! = SELECT MAX(marks) from tbl
```

but it fetched all marks except the highest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT uid, marks FROM (
  SELECT uid, marks, @rank := @rank + (@prevMarks != marks) rank, @prevMarks := marks
  FROM t, (SELECT @rank := 0, @prevMarks := 0) init
  ORDER BY marks
) s
WHERE rank = 2
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7eecd/1).

Another alternative without User Defined Variables:

```
SELECT t.uid, t.marks FROM t
JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT marks FROM t
  ORDER BY marks
  LIMIT 1, 1
) s
ON t.marks = s.marks
```

Output:

```
| UID | MARKS |
|-----|-------|
|   3 |    17 |
|   4 |    17 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LIMIT and ORDER BY

```
SELECT * FROM  TBL ORDER BY marks DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

There you ordered all students by marks fro hi to low. And then limit return from second (0 is first record) and return only one record.

If need all students with second mark, the use subquery

```
SELECT * FROM  TBL WHERE marks = (
  SELECT marks FROM  TBL ORDER BY marks DESC GROUP BY marks LIMIT 1,1
)
```

Comment: The question is asked to pull all records with the second highest score though...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE mark = (
    SELECT MAX(mark)
    FROM table
    WHERE mark <
    (
         SELECT MAX(mark)
         FROM table
    )
)
```

Comment: Since this is the SECOND highest mark. I took the approach that is the most intuitive. Also can be ported to other DBs without changing the query itself. However I do realize there are other more extensible ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT t.marks, t.uid, (

SELECT COUNT( marks ) +1
FROM tbl t1
WHERE t.marks < t1.marks
) AS rank
FROM tbl t
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

now you can use rank column with bit modification below

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT t.marks, t.uid, (

SELECT COUNT( marks ) +1
FROM tbl t1
WHERE t.marks < t1.marks
) AS rank
FROM tbl t
) alias where rank=n (2 here)
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work? I did a [fiddle](http://SQLfiddle.com/#!2/9108d/1) and it ain't working as it should. Your incrementing actually did the damage if there is a duplicate or more than one students that has same scores. I just wonder why this one is accepted.

Comment: if there are more than 1 student 1st then definitely there wont be anyone second. suppose in a class there are 2 guys with the highest score , in that case there wont be second position. There will be 2 1st position followed by third , not second

Comment: That's not case actually. I'm using the OP's data and it doesn't show as per OP's requirement.